# How to fill a Matrix in OpenCV with depthPixel array of OpenNi

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect, openni

i have a problem with OpenCV. After receiving a depth frame from the kinect i am trying to fill a Matrix (Mat of OpenCV) with the data returned by frame.getData().

The problem is the data in the depthMat matrix is not the same as the data contained in p1 array (from frame.getData()).

Do anyone knows why this, or how i have to fill my Matrix to get the right result.

```
DepthPixel* p1 = (DepthPixel*)frame.getData(); 
Mat depthMat = Mat(frame.getHeight(), frame.getWidth(), CV_16U, p1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code with a simple program of mine and it works perfectly.
Keep in mind however that you are doing a cast. The function `getData()` returns a `const void *` that your are casting into a non const pointer.
This is not a good practice.
It is non clear in the documentation if the data pointed by the pointer returned by `getData()` has an infinite lifespan.

A better way to do that is to copy the data into a buffer and then use this buffer to initialize the `cv::Mat`

```
   depth.readFrame(&depthFrame);
   DepthPixel *depthPixels = new DepthPixel[depthFrame.getHeight()*depthFrame.getWidth()];
   memcpy(depthPixels, depthFrame.getData(), depthFrame.getHeight()*depthFrame.getWidth()*sizeof(uint16_t));

   cv::Mat depthImage(depthFrame.getHeight(), depthFrame.getWidth(), CV_16U, depthPixels);
```

Comment: How can you verify the data in depthPixels and depthImage are equal?
I am trying to write it to a file(and casting) but it is printing different data, maybe the conversion from 16 bits during the writing is  the problem.
Example of output:
depthPixels: 2881, depthImage: 182717178 ...